# Would domain specific "must have" resources and package community wiki questions be appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this on meta rather than starting a question such as I have in mind to see what people think, first.

There are resources and packages that are of high relevance to subsets of the LaTeX community where those subsets are largely defined by academic discipline. For instance, Peter Smith's [LaTeX for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/) is an excellent resource for those working in logic, and the [feynman](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/help/Catalogue/entries/feynman.html) package would be of interests to physicists. I assume that there are like resources for chemists, and probably packages of interest to those who work in Category Theory that are not of general interest to mathematicians, etc., etc.

What would people think about community wiki questions like "What resources and packages do I need to know about as a working X" for various values of X?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, why not? But I'd prefer to have "real" question: ask this question for a particular value of X only if *you* are interested in the answers.

Comment: +1 for the keeping it real suggestion.